# Need help in moving divs to another div after an onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a container holding four divs. After I click on one div, the remaining three neeed to be appended to another div. How can I achieve this?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Week 4 Game</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "assets/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">

    <!-- Added link to the jQuery Library -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js" integrity="sha256-laXWtGydpwqJ8JA+X9x2miwmaiKhn8tVmOVEigRNtP4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "assets/javascript/game.js">      </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div class = "characters">
    <div class="charContainer darth">
        <h2 id="c1"></h2>
        <img class="vade" src="assets/images/vader.jpg">
        <p id="c1hp" data-hp = "120"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="charContainer luke">
        <h2 id="c2"></h2>
        <img class="skywalker" src="assets/images/luke.jpg">
        <p id="c2hp" data-hp = "100"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="charContainer won">
        <h2 id="c3"></h2>
        <img class="obi" src="assets/images/obiwan.jpg">
        <p id="c3hp" data-hp = "150"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="charContainer maul">
        <h2 id="c4"></h2>
        <img class="dmaul" src="assets/images/maul.png">
        <p id="c4hp" data-hp = "180"></p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="your">
    <h2>Your Character</h2>
    <!-- <img class="dmaul" src="assets/images/maul.png"> -->
    </div>
    <div id="enemies">
    <h2>Enemies</h2>
    <!-- <img class="dmaul" src="assets/images/maul.png"> -->
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

JQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       var yourCharacter;
       var enemy1;
       var enemy2;
       var enemy3;
      $('#c1').text("Darth Vader");
      $('#c2').text("Luke Skywalker");
      $('#c3').text("Obi Won");
      $('#c4').text("Darth Maul");
      var health = $('#c1hp').data('hp');
      $('#c1hp').html(health);
      var health = $('#c2hp').data('hp');
      $('#c2hp').html(health);
      var health = $('#c3hp').data('hp');
      $('#c3hp').html(health);
      var health = $('#c4hp').data('hp');
      $('#c4hp').html(health);

      $('.charContainer').on('click', function(){
      yourCharacter = $(this);
      $('#your').append(yourCharacter);
      enemy1 = $('.vader');
      $('#enemies').append(enemy1);

      })

      });
```

I need to append the remaind charContainers that were not clicked to the enemies container div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "your character" has already been moved by the time the rest of the characters need to be moved, the selector `'.characters>.charContainer'` (all the "charContainer" children of "characters") will not select your character (since it's already moved) - just the remaining characters

```
$('.charContainer').on('click', function() {
    $('#your').append($(this));
    $('.characters>.charContainer').each(function() {
        $('#enemies').append($(this));
    });
})
```

Alternate version using arrow function:

```
$('.charContainer').on('click', function() {
    $('#your').append($(this));
    $('.characters>.charContainer').each( (undefined, char) => { $('#enemies').append($(char)) } );
})
```

Or borrowing Tekebo's use of appendTo:

```
$('.charContainer').on('click', function() {
    $(this).appendTo('#your');
    $('.characters>.charContainer').appendTo('#enemies');
})
```

Note: the main advantage of using the children selector as opposed to the siblings of the clicked div or all divs of the 'charContainer' class is that it doesn't matter which order it's done in - the result will be the same.  (However, moving the clicked div last will cause more work to be done)

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the syntax '.characters>.charContainer', what does that mean?

Comment: @henhen the '.characters' means 'Elements with class "characters"'.  The '>' means "children of" and '.charContainer' means 'Elements with class "charContainer".  All together it means 'Elements with class "charContainer" that are children of elements with class "characters"'

Comment: I just noticed the char parameter in the .each function

Comment: what does that char do and where did it come from>

Comment: @henhen You're talking about the arrow function I guess.  An [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is similar to a normal function, but instead of doing `function(x) { ...code... }` you can do `x => code` or for a function with two params `(x,y) => { ...code...}`.  The jQuery [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function can take two parameters.  The first one I've replaced with `undefined` because I'm not using it.  The second one I called "char"

Comment: @henhen effectively the arrow function is the same as doing this: `function(undefined, char) { ... }`.  I've used the parameters in this case because `this` is not bound by arrow functions, but the 2nd parameter of `.each()` is the same value

Comment: So char is the same as value?

Comment: @henhen It's just a parameter.  They can have an valid identifier as a name

Comment: so I wouldnt even need a char in the parameter for the .each function in first example?

Comment: That parameter was unused and removed hours ago.  Sounds like you need to read some basic Javascript manuals.  Please accept one of the answers and move on.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me. You may want to add a check for equality, since the chosen div will be initially appended to enemies, then moved:

```
$('.charContainer').on('click', function(){
      $('.charContainer').each(function() {
        $('#enemies').append($(this));
      })
      yourCharacter = $(this);
      $('#your').append(yourCharacter);

  })
```

Comment: Will that method append the first div i clicked to the #your div? And also if this works i dont need the enemy1 = $vader any mire right?

Comment: Can you even assign the var enemy1 that way to a div class name and append it?

Comment: That's correct. I removed the vader code. This code moves all divs to the #enemies div, then your chosen div to the #your div. The end result is what you want. The only downside is that there is a small amount of extra work done, because the chosen div is moved twice. I've had some drinks; I'm sure you can handle the rest. :)

Comment: Also, no, you can't grab all elements of a class, and treat them as one variable, even if there is only one element with that class name. Use the edited code, not the code that still has the two .vader lines.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use **siblings()**, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".charContainer").on("click",function(){
    $(this).siblings().appendTo("#enemies");
    $(this).appendTo("#your");
  });
});
```

Comment: `appendTo` is cleaner as well